# plot 4 different plots inside 1 pdf

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames which i want to generate 3 plots from them and place them inside 1 pdf file as a single column.

i want all the plots to have the same x-axis limits(basically the same x-axis) even thought they differ in the name and how they were obtained.

the dataframes looks something like that:

d1

```
     X          Y       Z
0.04939317 -0.4622222  13651
0.03202451 -0.4261000  13401
0.09950793 -0.3233025  13151
0.11548556 -0.4637981  12486
0.09817597 -0.4751886  12236
0.15770701 -0.5819355  11986
```

and d2

```
   V0  V1   V2    V3   sign
   1   1  0.379 0.612   pos
   2   1  0.378 0.620   pos
   3   1  0.578 0.571   neg
   4   1  0.978 0.561   pos
   5   1  0.758 0.261   neg
   6   1  0.378 0.126   neg
```

***P.S : both data frames are bigger than this, this is only a part of them***

V0, V1 and Z range from 1 to 20000

the plots that i created are :

***From d2***

```
d2plot=ggplot(d1, aes(V0,V1, fill=sign)) + 
    geom_tile()+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("neg" = "yellow", "pos"="red")) +
    geom_vline(xintercept =10000 ) +
    geom_text(mapping=aes(x=10000,y=0, label="Stop"), 
    size=4, angle=90, vjust=-0.4, hjust=0)
```

***From d1***

```
d1plot = ggplot(d2) + 
    geom_errorbarh(aes(x=z,xmin=z-50,xmax=z+50, y=Y, height = 0.02),
    color="red")+ opts(legend.position = "none")  +
    geom_vline(xintercept = 10000) +
    geom_text(mapping=aes(x=10000,y=-0.3, label="Stop"), 
    size=4, angle=90, vjust=-0.4, hjust=0)
```

I've tried `grid.arrange(d1plot, d2plot, ncol=1)` but the x-axis is different for each plot, i tried changing the aspect ratio, but this will change the y-axis ..I've also tried to use `facet_wrap` but the problem that my x-axis values have different values, i just want the limits and breaks to be the same and the plots all be aligned in 1 column based on 1 x-axis to compare the value of the statistical methods in an easy way.

Comment: it's always easier to combine the data sets into one when you can, with a dummy variable used to facet the plot. In your situation that would probably require renaming some variables.

Comment: @baptiste: can you please guid me throw doing this ?? i have never used the facet

Comment: the wiki has [an example](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/Align-two-plots-on-a-page); beyond that you should post some data and reproducible code.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you set the x axis limits manually.

Add

```
+ coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1, 20000))
```

to each plot before combining them.

---

To achive different aspect ratios you can use

```
+ coord_fixed(xlim = c(1, 20000), ylim = c(1, 20000))
```

Change the `ylim` parameter for each plot to fit your actual data.

Comment: thank you .. this worked for me, but in this case the i'm just zooming. i'm plotting multiple plots in 1 pdf and this made all the x-axis at the same length. but now i can't change the y axis the same way .. because i don't want to zoom. i want the y-axis in some plots to be bigger(in length) than other plots. in other words (i want one square plot and the other plots have reduced y-axis size) is this possible ??

Answer (score 1):

You can also safe each individual plot to PDF and then open them in Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape and copy the elements into one PDF. This will also give you the opportunity to pimp your charts a bit and add some additional explaination etc. On this website (http://flowingdata.com) there are a number of tutorials that help you along but the basis is really simple. Safe R plot to PDF and open in Illustrator and you can select all elements (and thus also copy and combine them). Good luck!

Comment: i don't think it's a good idea to do this because i want the plots to be generated automatically and i have alot if plots .. so i can't change each one of them with photoshop